# Can we set module level attributes that could be modified within a session

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a module-level attribute to config file and want to do something like this..

```
# repo/__init__.py file
pass

# repo/config.py file
VERIFY_CERTS = True
```

and then, use this variable in other sub-modules

```
# repo/example.py
from repo.config import VERIFY_CERTS
def do_something():
    if VERIFY_CERTS:
        do something..
    else:
        do something else
```

Now, when I use this repo module in another script, I want to be able to do:

```
from repo.config import VERIFY_CERTS
VERIFY_CERTS = False
from repo.example import do_something
do_something()
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Edit: It is definitely not a duplicate of [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) since, it discusses something about mutable and immutable datatypes whereas, this one is about having a module level attribute that could be remembered in a session.
Modified variable names to clarify why I want to do this.

Comment: I know what you want to do, but I don't see the application of it. Like why do you need to `import X` at all, and why do you need to have an import that's not at the top of the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: @wjandrea renamed variables to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

From what I understand, you want to change the value of `VERIFY_CERTS` that `do_something()` uses.

Firstly, your example can be simplified like this:

**example.py**

```
VERIFY_CERTS = True
def do_something():
    print(VERIFY_CERTS)
```

**test.py**

```
from example import do_something
VERIFY_CERTS = False
do_something()
```

Running `test.py` will print `True`.

---

#### Solution

In `test.py`, simply import the whole module `example` (this is best practice for imports anyway), then set `example.VERIFY_CERTS`.

```
import example
example.VERIFY_CERTS = False
example.do_something()
```

Running this will print `False`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, this is just a small part of a big project and so I can't simplify it to move the config out. I got around this by using a different approach of using class variables instead.

Comment: @manji369 Oh, I assumed `repo` was a third-party module you didn't have control over, and you were just writing a script that uses it.